# How to write trigger to insert and update another table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to write trigger. When there is an entry in table1, table2 should get inserted with same values. And in some field in table1 is updated then respective field must get updated in table2. How can I know whether value is inserted or updated?

I am using inserted to insert value.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will know whether a value is inserted or updated in a trigger like this:

- on `INSERT`, the `inserted` dynamic table is populated with the new values
- on `UPDATE`, the `inserted` dynamic table is populated with the new values of the records that were updated, and the `deleted` dynamic table is poulated with the old values of the records that were updated

So basically, if the `deleted` table contains the id (assuming you have an id column) as in the `inserted` table, you can be assured that it was an `UPDATE` that caused the trigger.  If the `deleted` table is empty, conversely, it was an `INSERT`.

Comment: I have written After INSERT,UPDATE and I am using inserted dynamic tabel is it correct?

Comment: @user998533 as per my answer, you need to use both `inserted` and `deleted` tables in your trigger to truly know whether the trigger happen from `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  Make sense?

Comment: I have written like thiscreate trigger TestTrigger
on table1
after insert,update
as
    insert into table2
    select *
    from inserted
go  here... from inserted is there so I should write from inserted,deleted... right?????

Comment: @user998533 can you show me the `CREATE TABLE` batches for `table1` and `table2`?  I'll write the trigger to show you my train of thought.  Please edit your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

use this trigger to solve your problem..
create TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_Assets_Tran]
 ON [dbo].[AssetMaster]
AFTER INSERT , UPDATE
AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @isnum TINYINT;

SELECT @isnum = COUNT(*) FROM inserted;

IF (@isnum = 1)
    INSERT INTO AssetTransaction
    select [AssetId],[Brandname],[SrNo],[Modelno],[Processor],[Ram],[Hdd],[Display],[Os],[Office],[Purchasedt]
      ,[Expirydt],[Vendor],[VendorAMC],[Typename],[LocationName],[Empid],[CreatedBy],[CreatedOn],[ModifiedBy]
      ,[ModifiedOn],[Remark],[AssetStatus],[Category],[Oylstartdt],[Oylenddt],[Configuration]
      ,[AStatus],[Tassign]

FROM inserted;
  ELSE
    RAISERROR('some fields not supplied', 16, 1)
      WITH SETERROR;
END